# Mysqldump не делается развертывание

Tags: mysql, dump

Делаю дамб базы, все данные копируются нормально, а когда необходимо установить этот дамп в другую базу, он пишет dump completed, а ничего не копируется. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: mysqldump только делает дамп, а не раздампливает.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
mysql -u vp -h 192.168.0.103 -p root vpraktik < "путь_к\dump_test.sql"
```

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/105776/how-do-i-restore-a-dump-file-from-mysqldump

Comment: Спасибо помогло.